# Visual Studio C++

Tags: компиляция

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, с чего начинать изучение Visual Studio C++ с нуля.

Answer (score -2):

Есть очень хороший сайт https://ravesli.com/uroki-cpp/ который поможет тебе. Но читай всё сначала, ибо дальше может быть непонятно.

Все начинают с:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::cout << "Hello, world!";
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello, world уже было и прошло. Проблема была в том что учебные пособия по полторы тысячи страниц вгоняют в тоску. Но начать изучение как-то надо. Очень помог в этом ютуб канал ЭкстримКоде. Именно их стиль подачи информации  вперемешку с шутками и мемами способствовал именно НАЧАТЬ ИЗУЧЕНИЕ С++. Кроме них нашлось много материала. Но! Гнусавость голосов и тоскливо-неинтересная подача материала не способствовала появлению желания смотреть дальше. Спасибо за советы. Начало всё таки случилось. Сейчас изучение уже в процессе.